# Django values_list() lowercase

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have query set that I am exporting to CSV.

```
models.One2OneInfoLog.objects.filter(one_2_one_info=pk).values_list('name', 'location', 'created').order_by('created')
```

I want the 'name' field to be in lowercase. Is their a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Database Function 'Lower'](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/database-functions/#lower) to convert to lowercase:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Lower

models.One2OneInfoLog.objects.filter(one_2_one_info=pk).values_list(Lower('name'), 'location', 'created').order_by('created')
```

Comment: Is their a way to format date field. It seems when outputted to CSV I lost hours from the results when shown via template.